# Qt5 debian packaging for Ubuntu

Tags: qt, ubuntu, packaging

I have problems with packaging Qt5 application on Ubuntu 13.04. While I was using Qt4 I packaged my apps using pbuilder, but now pbuilder can't find any Qt5 dependencies. I tried with cmake but cmake can't find QMediaPlayer (which I use in my app).

Is there any other way to package my Qt5 app on Ubuntu.